# How to get 'Deployment group's target's capabilities in Azure Devops using Powershell rest

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I am trying to get a **target's capabilities** under **azure devops deployment group** using Powershell REST API.  However I am not sure which URL will work to fetch those capabilities. My Powershell script is working till fetching status of 'targets'. Please help if there is anything we can do to fetch capabilities.

Below is my script which is working till fetching target details:

```
$projects = "testing"
$projectlist = $projects.split(';')
$PAT = "#######################################33"
$Header =  @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)")) }      
foreach($projectName in $projectlist){
    write-host "================================================="
    $baseURL = "https://dev.azure.com/abc/$($projectName)/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups" 
    $deploymentgroup=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/abc/$($projectName)/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups?api-version=6.0-preview.1" -Method get -Headers $Header
    $deploymentgroupsname=$deploymentgroup.value.name
    foreach($deploymentgroupname in $deploymentgroupsname){
    $deploymentGroupURL = "$($baseURL)?name=$($deploymentgroupname)&api-version=6.0"
    try{
      $deploymentgroup=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$deploymentGroupURL" -Method get -Headers $Header
    }catch{
      write-host "URL is not accessible - $deploymentGroupURL"
    }
    $deploymentGroupResponse=$deploymentgroup.value
    $deploymentGroupid=$deploymentGroupResponse.id
    try{
      $targets=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/abc/$($projectName)/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/$($deploymentGroupid)/targets?api-version=6.0-preview.1" -Method get -Headers $Header
    }catch{
      write-host "URL is not accessible - $deploymentGroupURL"
    }
    if($null -ne $deploymentGroupId){
        $targets.value.agent|select name, status|%{
        $hostname=$_.name
        $Status=$_.status
        if($status -eq "offline"){
            $targetURL = "$($baseURL)/$deploymentGroupId/targets?name=$($hostName)&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
            try{ 
                $target = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $targetURL -Method get -Headers $Header).value 
                $targetId = $target.id ;
                if($null -ne $targetId){
                   $url = "$($baseURL)/$deploymentGroupId/targets/$($targetId)?api-version=6.0"
                   try{
                    write-host "Projectname is : $projectName"
                    write-host "deploymentGroupname is : $deploymentgroupname"  
                    write-host "Server $hostname is not pingble"
                    }
                   catch{
                      write-host "TARGET DELETE ERROR: $hostName";Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
                    }
                }
                else{ 
                    write-host "Target $hostName NOT Found in DeploymentGroup $environment."
                }
             }catch {
                write-host "TARGET LIST ERROR";Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
              }
         }         
        }
    }else{
           write-host "DeploymentGroup $deploymentgroupname NOT FOUND in $projectName"
        }    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To to fetch capabilities of the Deployment Group Targets, you can use the Rest API: [Targets - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#deploymenttargetexpands). You need to add the parameter: `$expand=capabilities` in the URL.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/{deploymentGroupId}/targets/{targetId}?$expand=capabilities&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Then you will get the capabilities of the Deployment Group Targets.

To use the Rest API URL in the PowerShell, you can use the following format:

```
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/{deploymentGroupId}/targets/{targetId}?`$expand=capabilities&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
```

**Update:**

When we add the `$expand=capabilities` in the Rest API url, it will return the capabilities in the API Response.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Hi @kevin - The URL shared by you giving output but not these details that are under capabilities, e.g - USERDOMAIN,Agent.version, Agent.os etc

Comment: Yes. I can understand your requirement. When we add the parameter: $expand=capabilities to the url it will return the capabilities. Refer to my update.

Comment: On the other hand, when you use the url in the PowerShell, you need to add  character: `  before the $expand. for example: https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/{deploymentGroupId}/targets/{targetId}?`$expand=capabilities&api-version=6.0-preview.1

Comment: Glad to know that the API can work for you! If the answer can solve the issue, you may consider accepting it. It will be helpful to other members who have the same issue